# Swift error type server response for wrong input from rest API

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, codable

I hope all you well. I have a question. I have a simple login page with email and password and also I have a user object like that

```
// MARK: - UserModel
struct UserModel: Codable {
    let error: Bool
    let desc: String
    let user: User
    let token: String
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let email, firstName, lastName, lang: String
    let status: Int
    let referer, star: String?
    let phone: String?
    let ip: String?
    let birth, idNumber: String?
    let regionID: String?
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, email
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case lang, status, referer, star, phone, ip, birth
        case idNumber = "id_number"
        case regionID = "region_id"
        case createdAt, updatedAt
    }
}
```

the return type is the upper one(UserModel). If the user entered his/her credentials true there is no problem. But troubles starts if he/she entered the wrong credentials. I can not parse the return value from the server. Always give me error that line.

[image: Error Image]

And the console output is:

```
Rentover[2343:150674] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Bool, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "error", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Bool but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file
```

Here is my login request function. I used codable for simplicity.

```
class func requestLogIn(router: Router, completion: @escaping (Result<UserModel, Error>) -> ()) {

    guard let url = setUrlComponents(router: router).url else { return }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = router.method

    if router.method == "POST"{
        let model = LoginModel(email: router.parameters[0], password: router.parameters[1])
        urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(model)
    }

    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard response != nil else {
            print("no response")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no data")
            return
        }

        let responseObject = try! JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self, from: data)
        print(responseObject.user)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.success(responseObject))
        }


    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

And here is my error struct.

```
struct LogInError: Codable, Error{
    let error: Bool
    let desc: String
    let fields: [String] ----> 'Edit here old: let fileds: [String' 
}
```

And last my real call function is like that

```
    NetworkService.requestLogIn(router: Router.login(email: nameTextField.text!, passowrd: passwordTextField.text!)) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let userModel):
            print("RESULT SUCCESS")
            print("Hello \(userModel.user.firstName)")

            let selectedVC = UIUtils.checkUserStatus(status: userModel.user.status)
            self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectedVC, animated: true)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("RESULT FAILED")
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I followed [that medium](https://medium.com/@rinradaswift/networking-layer-in-swift-5-111b02db1639) link for creating my router and network service. I am very glad and thankful if you help me with that issue. Or give me some advice about networking api's and usage.

[Edit For error response from server]
My request and response message-body frame is also like that:
[image: Request Body and response message]

Have a nice day. And good codding.

Comment: The error says that in case of an error the value for key `error` is a dictionary. So it seems that `LogInError` doesn't match the JSON structure. Please add the JSON string. And never `try!` in a `Decodable` context. Always `catch` and handle the error.

Comment: Hello @vadian, unfortunately my JSON structure is right. I am using postman. My question is, when the response is the error from my rest service. How can I detect and decode that error response respect to particular error.

Comment: As I said, add the JSON which is returned on error.

Comment: @vadian I edited the question. Can you look it again.

Comment: fileds != fields. try! means "In case of an error crash the program and destroy any evidence of what went wrong". try means "In case of an error return the error which can then be printed".

Comment: Thank you very much @gnasher729 but my problem begins now. my function result type is UserModel. However, if user input was wrong it retunes LogInError. How can i solve that problem also ?

Comment: Create an enum with two cases UserModel and LoginError and return that enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decode two different JSON strings a convenient solution is an enum with associated types because it can represent the `success` and `failure` cases very descriptively.

First it decodes the common `error` key and then it decodes `UserModel` or `LogInError`

```
enum Response : Decodable {
    case success(UserModel), failure(LogInError)

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case error }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let hasError = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .error)
        if hasError {
            let errorContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let errorData = try errorContainer.decode(LogInError.self)
            self = .failure(errorData)
        } else {
            let successContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let successData = try successContainer.decode(UserModel.self)
            self = .success(successData)
        }
    }
}
```

Use it

```
class func requestLogIn(router: Router, completion: @escaping (Result<Response, Error>) -> ()) {

    ...

    do {
        let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        print(responseObject)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.success(responseObject))
        }
    } catch {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

and

```
NetworkService.requestLogIn(router: Router.login(email: nameTextField.text!, passowrd: passwordTextField.text!)) { (response) in
    switch response {
    case .success(let result):
        switch result {
            case .success(let userModel): 
                print("RESULT SUCCESS")
                print("Hello \(userModel.user.firstName)")

                let selectedVC = UIUtils.checkUserStatus(status: userModel.user.status)
                self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectedVC, animated: true)
            case .failure(let errorData): 
                print(errorData)
        }

    case .failure(let error):
        print("RESULT FAILED")
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Declare `LoginError` as a standard Decodable struct

```
struct LogInError: Decodable {
```

Comment: I implemented your answer and it's worked. Also really logical thank you very much for time. Just last question in your answer you changed the LogInError: Codable to LogInError: Decodable. Reason is that struct won't related to any post request (any encoding process)?

Comment: `LoginError` and  `LoginModel` is not the same.

Comment: Yes, so there is no need to stay inherited from Decodable for LoginError?

Comment: `LoginError` must conform to `Decodable` unlike `LoginModel`

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! Have a nice day.